# Install old Java8 version

Tags: java, jdk, synaptic, jre

I've installed Java 1.8.0_201, but i need the 8.161 version to run a software. I try with Synaptic but i can't downgrade java.

I try do download the .tar file from this website but i don't know how to install because there's not the configure file: https://www.itechtics.com/java-8-update-161-offline-installers-operating-systems/#Java_8_Update_161_Direct_Download_Links

I don't need to use Java i just need to run the software

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried uninstalling what you downloaded and then install the actual version you need to run the said software?

Comment: I can't find a way to install Java 8.161, if i run $ sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default the version installed is the 8.201